# How to map CAPSLOCK to ESC and ESC to CAPSLOCK in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

So I want to map both keys:

1. Capslock to Esc
2. Esc to Capslock

And this script works for `Capslock` to `Esc` but it doesn't really work for `Esc` to `Capslock`. It causes a `Capslock` then `Esc` to be sent. I only want a `Capslock` sent:

```
Capslock::Esc
Esc::Capslock
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1303809

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Griffin's Comment

```
$Capslock::Esc
$Esc::Capslock
```

The problem that you had was that one of the hotkeys you had was triggering another, which can be prevented by using the $ modifier.

From the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm):

> **This is usually only necessary if the script uses the Send command to
> send the keys that comprise the hotkey itself, which might otherwise
> cause it to trigger itself**. The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to
> be used to implement this hotkey, which as a side-effect prevents the
> Send command from triggering it. The $ prefix is equivalent to having
> specified #UseHook somewhere above the definition of this hotkey.